# Xamarin Forms Maps MoveToLastRegionOnLayoutChange not working as expected

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, maps, renderer

I have an issue with the Forms Maps.
When I drag the map and move away to a different screen, I see the map back to the last location set using "MoveToRegion" when I resume back the map screen. As per the documentation, setting MoveToLastRegionOnLayoutChange to False should prevent this behavior but it doesn't.

I didn't specifically test this property for screen rotation, but Renderer doesn't change on app sleep and resume.

Tried with below:

- Xamarin Forms V16.6.000.1062
- Android V8.1
- Visual Studio 2019 V16.6.3

---

**UPDATE:** I realized that it is not merely a case of Page resume, but the page is rendered as below:

```
mapInstance = MapsPage.SelfInstance ?? new MapsPage();
Detail = new NavigationPage(mapInstance);
```

Here, I store the page instance in **SelfInstance** the first time it is instantiated, so the **page is not initialized again**. Result below:

[image: Map Issue Gif]

Here is the [link to code sample](https://github.com/SnapADrag0n/Recentering-MapNavigation) I created with above result.

Comment: The property will work when a layout change occurs. In your case , navigation between pages will not invoke the property .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT So this property doesn't prevent re-centering of map in cases other than Layout change? Is it the default behavior of Maps to re-center on switching page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reported this on XF Github page:

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11488